# How can split the emission of an RxJava Observable<Map<String, List<Integer>> into multiple ones?

Tags: java, android, functional-programming, rx-java2

I'm trying to split the emissions of an `RxJava.Observable<Map<String, List<Integer>>` into multiple `RxJava.Observable<Map<String, List<Integer>>`. Each emission should include a partition of the original list all in the original order. It is guaranteed that each list has the same size and `(list.size() % partitionSize) == 0`.

Example:

```
{ 
    "a": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], 
    "b": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8] 
}
```

to

```
// First emission
{ 
    "a": [0,1,2], 
    "b": [0,1,2] 
}
// Second emission
{ 
    "a": [3,4,5], 
    "b": [3,4,5] 
}
// Third emission
{ 
    "a": [6,7,8], 
    "b": [6,7,8] 
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You want to create a `List` of the new splitted `Maps`?

Comment: No, I want to emit new `Map`s with splitted `List`s.

Comment: I understand that, but my questions  is if you want a `List` that contains the new `Maps`: `List<Map<String, List<Integer>>`

Answer (score 0):

I would use `streams`for that job. One way would be:

```
Map<String, List<Integer>> map = Map.of(
        "a", List.of(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8),
        "b", List.of(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8));

int size = map.values().stream().mapToInt(list -> list.size()).max().getAsInt();

int partitionSize = IntStream.iterate(2, i -> i + 1)
        .limit(size)
        .filter(i -> size % i == 0)
        .findFirst()
        .orElse(1);

int splitSize = Math.round(size / partitionSize);

List<Map<String, List<Integer>>> maps = IntStream.range(0, partitionSize)
        .mapToObj(i -> map.entrySet().stream().collect(
                Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, 
                                entry -> entry.getValue().subList(i * splitSize, (i + 1) * splitSize))))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

maps.forEach(System.out::println);
```

**Output:**

```
{a=[0, 1, 2], b=[0, 1, 2]}
{a=[3, 4, 5], b=[3, 4, 5]}
{a=[6, 7, 8], b=[6, 7, 8]}
```

**Note:** I assume you don't know the `partitionSize`, that all `Lists` are neither `null` nor empty, and all have the same size and `list.size() > 1`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Actually I forgot to mention that I want to use the `RxJava.Observable` which should emit (looking at the given example) 3 emissions for each new `Map`, instead of emitting a list of the new `Map`s.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with `RxJava.Observable` and can't help with that part. Hope someone else can take it from here ;)

Answer (score 0):

You should `buffer(size)` each list for the given argument `partitionSize` then map for each emitted buffered list from each element in the key set.

```
 fromIterable(map.entries).flatMap { entry ->
        fromIterable(entry.value).buffer(Math.min(entry.value.size, partionSize))
    }.flatMap {
        fromIterable(map.keys).flatMap { key -> just(key to it) }
    }.subscribe(::println)
```

Output:

```
(a, [0, 1, 2])
(b, [0, 1, 2])
(a, [3, 4, 5])
(b, [3, 4, 5])
(a, [6, 7, 8])
(b, [6, 7, 8])
(a, [0, 1, 2])
(b, [0, 1, 2])
(a, [3, 4, 5])
(b, [3, 4, 5])
(a, [6, 7, 8])
(b, [6, 7, 8])
```